# Phaser Multiple lines in one text? Is there a way to set images?

Tags: string, phaser-framework, phaserjs

For a game I'm making in Phaser, there are two things I'm concerned about.

1st. When using the setText method, or just setting a string in general, is there a way for the resulting string to have multiple lines? I'm asking because just hitting enter isn't working, and if I can't get this to work, I'm going to have to stay up all night making speech bubble sprites, each with different text in them.

2nd. Is there a way to set a new image to an existing sprite, similar to how the setText method sets a new bunch of words to a string.

If it helps find an answer, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to you first part of the question **yes** it is possible use `\n` or just pass a string array.

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Line 1\nLine 2')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        
        
    this.add.text(110, 10, [
            'Array Line 1',
            'Array Line 2',
            ])
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

To answer the second part the answer is also **yes**: depening if it is a static or animated sprite you can use:

1. static: Just use the function `setTexture('newImageKey')`, [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Image.html#setTexture__anchor)
2. animation: just create an animation with as usual and for switching just call the function `play('newAnimationKey')` [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#play__anchor)

> Images and Animation Examples don't work well on stackoverflow, so I hope the explaination is enough